# MapKit iOS 6.1 or Google Maps API 1.1.0?

Tags: google-maps, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios6.1

I'm consider if I should use `MapKit` or `Google Maps API`, I'm working with iOS 6.1.

I'll implement on my app some features with maps, like pins, tracer routes with preview user choice, etc..

`Google Maps` has a new API version since 21 feb.

- `MapKit` is consistent? I read about many bugs on the apple maps.
- It's more difficult to use the `Google API`? I'll have legal
  problems?
- How I know what system I have to use?

I know there are here a lot of questions about it, but I didn't find about the `Google API` (released since the begin of the year) and the MapKit on iOS 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use map kit. It has been improved massively and majority of the initial bugs have been dealt with. Although google map API is a nice work around but i still prefer map kit since its native iOS and functions smoother than google.